# Delphi XE [DCC Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: DBG2886

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Can somebody help me what could be the reason for this error? Delphi XE throws this very often now when building our already quite large project. Impossible for us to isolate the cause. The only help now is to quit Delphi, open it again and rebuild. Google search for exactly this error number is void.

Thanks

Comment: *Internal error* means that something happened that was totally unexpected, and the complier/linker/debugger doesn't have any idea how to handle it. The error message is only meaningful to those who write the internals (thus the name *internal error*). If you can figure out how to reproduce it in a small test case, you can open a bug report (although since your Delphi version is 10 behind the current, it won't get fixed).

Comment: Forgot to mention: The DBG indicates that the problem is happening in the debugger, so you've at least narrowed it down that far. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a pretty much the same problem while building a large (> 4mln lines) `Delphi XE` project. In our case compilation failed with the bunch of internal compiler errors, because of the memory leakage by the compiler. Partly a problem could be solved by using an unofficial [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/). Another option is to use a `make` file for building.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The IDE fix pack seems to help, will test more and longer time yet and report then.

Comment: The fix pack surely helps I don't get some other internal AVs but I still get the DBG2886 error sometimes (not so often as before). It seems that only external build (msbuild?) will help here at 100% or maybe using newer Delphi.

Comment: How do you call MSBuild from inside the IDE?